Getting and Setting custom Json attribute in Laravel 11
I have a Model called Service which migration is as follows:
Schema::create( 'services', function( Blueprint $table ){
    $table->id();
    $table->json( 'data' );

    $table->dateTime( 'created_at' )->useCurrent();
    $table->dateTime( 'updated_at' )->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
    $table->dateTime( 'deleted_at' )->nullable();
} );

The idea is to store the information in the Json column, so for example I will have a name, priority, style or an icon. I want to create those attributes for my Service model using the new Laravel 11 approach:
/**
 * Returns the name attribute
 *
 * @return Attribute
 */
protected function style(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: /* Some getter function */,
        set: /* Some setter function */
    );
}

I would expect to be able to do stuff like:
$s = new Service();
$s->name = 'My service';
$s->save();

Or
$s = Service::find( 1 );
echo $s->name;

I tried implementig the name() function like this:
/**
 * The name attribute
 *
 * @return Attribute
 */
protected function name(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn () => data_get( $this->data, 'name' ),
        set: fn ( string $value ) => data_set( $this->data, 'name', $value )
    );
}

I think data_set receives $this->data as & parameter, and that's the problem. I think I'm very close to solving this, thank you.
